# bash script that print all the lines that has my 2 letter country code on the last column of each line

Tags: bash, scripting

e.g. command

./show PH

then bash script will print all the lines that has PH on the last column of each line

output should be:

```
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   PH
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   PH
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   PH
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   PH
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   PH
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   PH
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   PH
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   PH
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   PH
```

file.txt {content}

```
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   KR
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   KR
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   AU
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   DE
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   PE
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   PH
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   PH
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   PH
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   PH
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   CA
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   PH
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   PH
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   PH
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   PH
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   PH
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   AU
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   CA
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   CA
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   US
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   US
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   US
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   US
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it. Try to show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: `grep '\sPH$' file.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sed, `show.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -n "/[ \t]*${1}$/p" file
```

`./show.sh AU` outputs :

```
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   AU
test    sample      1234    234543 111  T   x   6   AU
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk -v search='PH' '$NF==search' file
```

The program checks whether the last field in the line contains the value `PH`, if this evaluates to true awk will print that line which is the default action. Note that `NF` is the *number of fields* in awk. `$1` accesses the first field, `$2` the second and so on. `$NF` can be used to access the last field.

Having this your bash script should look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v search="$1" '$NF==search'
```

Answer (score 0):

With Grep:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Get Code from command line
CountryCode="$1"

MyFile="File.txt"

if [[ ! "$CountryCode" ]]; then
    echo "No CountryCode Supplied"
    exit 1;
fi

grep -P "$CountryCode$" "$MyFile"
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
./show.sh "PH"
```